# Symfony 2.3 EntityManager is closed error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

These last days I get an error like `The EntityManager is closed` in Symfony 2.3. I searched it in google but I couldn't find any good solutions. I get these error in only one controller and it works 100 times smoothly, only I get error 2-3 times.

Is there anybody get these error?

Comment: Make sure you don't have an edge condition somewhere calling $entityManager->close();  Once the em is closed then it can no longer be used.

Comment: If there was an Exception thrown while attempting to commit SQL statements during the transaction, Doctrine catches them, then precedes to close the Entity Manager, but the Exception is rethrown so you should be able to catch it and see the error message (I think that's how it works anyway)